# how to animate atoms finding and binding to eachother

Tags: particles

Is there a way to animate for example atoms finding each other, binding to each other. For example by means of different particle systems.

thanks in advance
Ben.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at using force fields physics,
Here is a short tutorial that might get you on the right track:
https://youtu.be/ebgHGmjf5Nc